# Introducing artificial errors in Protocol Buffer stream

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, protocol-buffers, packet-loss

Is there a way to introduce artificial errors in a Protobuf stream from server to client running on the same PC? In this case, the data in question is a camera stream that should be corrupted by a lossy channel. Alternatively is it possible to have a streaming wrapper around the Protobuf object?

Answer (score 2):

What's stopping you?
It's just binary data, you can do whatever you want to it in your own code.

However, it is very unlikely that even a slightly corrupted protobuf stream would be decodeable, because the parser aborts on first error and the format is not self-synchronizing.